# Absolutely positioned element jumping down on :active - but why?

Tags: css, css-position

I have an anchor with a piece wrapped in `<em>` tags so that I can absolutely position then on top of the anchor background sprite, which sits off to the left of the rest of the anchor text.

Everything is well, except on :active the absolutely positioned bit is jumping down about 20 pixels.

And I'm having a tough time diagnosing this one since you're kind of limited to inspecting :active states with firebug, since you have to actually be clicking the element to get the :active rules to show up!

Here's the page http://cure.org/brant and the piece in question are the green call to action buttons. If you click and hold (or simply click) you'll see the html text on the buttons jumps downward as described.

FYI the styles for this page are in the brant.css file, not the main.min.css

Comment: Just my $ 0.02: when hovering over links they turn green; contrast is way too low then, your text is hardly readable.

Comment: Thanks for the input Marcel - def worth more than $.02. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `position` is being set to `relative` in this rule:

```
a:active {
    outline:0 none;
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
```

Add `position:static` to this rule to override the `a:active` behaviour:

```
li.lp-ask-butn-sm a:hover, li.lp-ask-butn-sm a:focus, li.lp-ask-butn-sm a:active {
    background-position:left -50px;
    color:#2F2511;
    position:static; /* add this */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok I found it,

you have a rule that does this:

```
a.active 
{
    position:relative;
}
```

which is giving your active buttons relative positioning. 
Adding static positioning to li.lp-ask-butn-sm a:hover, li.lp-ask-butn-sm a:focus, li.lp-ask-butn-sm a:active in

> brant.css

helps

```
li.lp-ask-butn-sm a:hover, li.lp-ask-butn-sm a:focus, li.lp-ask-butn-sm a:active
{
    position:static;
}
```

However, I'm curious as to what about relative positioning is causing it to shift downwards. 
Update: according to firebug, the link, and the strong are still in the right position, however it is being rendered lower. This is perplexing.

At any rate, the solution I posted slightly about this paragraph solves the problem.

Comment: Um yeah. That certainly is perplexing. But thanks for helping me find a solution!